# Angular js watch on an Array of objects on a Select tag with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to watch on select tag with ng-repeat and disable the save button.I have a set up like this.

- Initially i will have three select boxes with values, where user has to select at least one select value out of three boxes to get Save btn enabled

  - user will also have a provision to add more select boxes.

Now,how do i watch the select boxes,if we have 5 select boxes -how can we watch all of them and enable/disable the Save button ,if none got selected.

Here is a fiddle link..similar to my situation: `Js fiddle`
Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same object as model for all `ng-select`s:

```
$scope.selectedValues = {};
```

Then each select box inside `ng-repeat` will use as model different object property:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedValues['campus_' + $index]">
    <option>Select a campus</option>
    <option>Campus 1</option>
    <option>Campus 2</option>
    <option>Campus 3</option>        
</select>
```

To check whether all values are filled you'll watch the `selectedValues` for changes with last parameter set to `true`:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedValues', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // Check whether all values in $scope.selectedValues are filled
    var allFilled = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedValues, function(value, key) {
        if (!value) {
            allFilled = false;
        }
    });

    if (allFilled) {
        // enable button
    } else {
        // disable button
    }
}, true);
```

The last parameter `true` is essential because it tells Angular to compare all values in the object. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope.

Comment: Hi Martin..could you pls help me in checking for atleast one select box is filled..Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer. If it doesn't work create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Hi Martin.. i have written a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gq54mc56/. Here,i want to enable\disable the save button.Once , the user clicks on add another, say five times..I want to check whether atleast one select element has the value selected out of five.Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can put all the selects inside a form and set them as required.
In the button, you valid the ng-disabled tag if de form is $invalid.

Example:

```
<ng-form name="selectForm">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.name" name="select" ng-required="true">
    <option>Select a campus</option>
    <option>Campus 1</option>
    <option>Campus 2</option>
    <option>Campus 3</option>        
  </select>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="selectForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: Actually the scenario that iam trying is already inside a form and I am using ng-repeat in a table.Again in the table ,i have 4 columns having four select tags ,out of them one is mandatory.Could you pls help me in getting atleast one select box filled so that other select boxes are not mandatory to fill.

Comment: Well Krishna. I think the solution for you is declare in ng-model a list like the example below: selectedItems['campus' + $index]. 

And, in controller, make a function that searchs in this array for any value of the key you declared in. If have any, you return true, else, false. This will make help to disable or not the button.